# I have granted usage permission on db,schema,stage,storage intergation to new role but he is not able to list/desc the stage

Tags: list, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, stage, snowflake-schema

```
Use database citibike;
use warehouse COMPUTE_WH;
use role ACCOUNTADMIN;
```

---

```
list @citibike_trips; -- external stage with storage integration

CREATE USER USER1 PASSWORD='abc123';
CREATE role BasicRole;
```

----------granting access to user role

```
show grants on stage citibike_trips;  -- sysadmin owner
grant usage on stage citibike_trips to role BasicRole; -- grants  usage stage to new role
grant usage on database citibike to role BasicRole;
grant usage on warehouse COMPUTE_WH to role BasicRole;
grant usage on schema public to role BasicRole;
grant usage on table TRIPS to role BasicRole;
```

----accountadmin has created the storage integration and grant access is given to role Basic Role

----------checking grants

```
show grants on stage citibike_trips;  -- 1) sysadmin owner 2) usage BasicRole
show grants on warehouse COMPUTE_WH; 

grant role BasicRole to USER USER1;
```

------------when user user1 is logging in with user id and listing stage he is unable to  list

```
USE ROLE BasicRole;
USE DATABASE citibike;
USE WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH;

list @citibike_trips;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to AWS S3 external stage access, Correct?
What is the error?
Have you followed the configuration steps mentioned here- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html

Comment: yes external stage

Comment: error is like stage fullyqualified stage name  dose not exist or not authorized . but i have granted to user usage privileage